# how to flip a regression table in stargazer?

Tags: r, xtable, stargazer

I would like to "flip" the row/columns in a regression table.

The latest `stargazer` manuals says that now the `flip` argument also works with regression tables (previously it only worked with summary stats).

However I am unable to make it work. Here is an example with `stargazer` `5.2.1`

```
library(stargazer)
stargazer(attitude)

linear.1 <- lm(rating ~ complaints + privileges + learning + raises + critical, data=attitude)
linear.2 <- lm(rating ~ complaints + privileges + learning, data=attitude)

## create an indicator dependent variable, and run a probit model

attitude$high.rating <- (attitude$rating > 70)
probit.model <- glm(high.rating ~ learning + critical + advance, data=attitude, family = binomial(link = "probit"))

stargazer(linear.1, linear.2, probit.model, title= "Regression Results", type = 'text', flip = TRUE)
```

gives :

```
> stargazer(linear.1, linear.2, probit.model, title="Regression Results", type = 'text', flip = FALSE)
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be usednumber of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
Regression Results
=============================================================================
                                       Dependent variable:                   
                    ---------------------------------------------------------
                                       rating                     high.rating
                                         OLS                        probit   
                             (1)                    (2)               (3)    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
complaints                 0.692***               0.682***                   
                           (0.149)                (0.129)                    

privileges                  -0.104                 -0.103                    
                           (0.135)                (0.129)                    

learning                    0.249                  0.238*          0.164***  
                           (0.160)                (0.139)           (0.053)  

raises                      -0.033
```

The table is just the regular one with variables as columns. 
Instead, I am looking for something like

```
Regression Results
=====================================
            complaints   privileges
-------------------------------------
model1      0.692***      etc
            (0.149) 
model2      0.14**    
            (0.049)
model3      0.692    
            (0.149)
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks!

Comment: Don't even see the word "flip" in the vignette and that is not the description of its effect on the help page. " ... when printing summary statistic tables or vector, matrix and data frame content."

Comment: its in the manual bro. the big stargazer pdf

Comment: Yeah, Ye'r so kewl. Why bother giving good references.

Comment: @42- come on dude... its a joke... here it is https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/stargazer.pdf thanks!

Comment: Which has the text I gave

Comment: and this one as well `– regression, summary statistic and data frame table can now be flipped (argument flip)`...

Comment: I agree, it's much more useful to have each model as a row in your summary table and the covariates as columns. It's a shame, because otherwise I think that Stargazer is really great, and the only way to do this transpose seems to be a lot of manual data wrangling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, my friend. I hope this helps.

```
stargazer(coef(summary(linear.1)), coef(summary(linear.2)), coef(summary(probit.model)), title= "Regression Results", type = 'text', flip = TRUE)
```

**Output**:

```
Regression Results
======================================================================
            (Intercept) complaints privileges learning raises critical
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Estimate      11.011      0.692      -0.104    0.249   -0.033  0.015  
Std. Error    11.704      0.149      0.135     0.160   0.202   0.147  
t value        0.941      4.649      -0.769    1.560   -0.165  0.105  
Pr(> | t| )    0.356      0.0001     0.450     0.132   0.870   0.917  
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Regression Results
======================================================
            (Intercept) complaints privileges learning
------------------------------------------------------
Estimate      11.258      0.682      -0.103    0.238  
Std. Error     7.318      0.129      0.129     0.139  
t value        1.538      5.296      -0.799    1.707  
Pr(> | t| )    0.136     0.00002     0.432     0.100  
------------------------------------------------------

Regression Results
=================================================
            (Intercept) learning critical advance
-------------------------------------------------
Estimate      -7.476     0.164    -0.001  -0.062 
Std. Error     3.570     0.053    0.044    0.042 
z value       -2.094     3.079    -0.013  -1.472 
Pr(> | z| )    0.036     0.002    0.990    0.141 
-------------------------------------------------
>
```

**EDIT** after the OPs clarification:

```
    options(stringsAsFactors = F, scipen=999)
    model1 <- data.frame(t(coef(summary(linear.1))))
model1$stats <- rownames(model1)
model2 <- data.frame(t(coef(summary(linear.2))))
model2$stats <- rownames(model2)
model3 <- data.frame(t(coef(summary(probit.model))))
model3$stats <- rownames(model3)


x <- dplyr::bind_rows(model1 = model1, model2=model2,
                 model3 = model3, .id = "Name")
x <- x[,c(1,8,2:7,9 )] #rearranging the terms
stargazer(x, type="text", summary=F)
```

**Output**:

```
    =========================================================================================
    Name     stats    X.Intercept. complaints privileges learning raises critical advance
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  model1  Estimate      11.011      0.692      -0.104    0.249   -0.033  0.015          
2  model1 Std. Error     11.704      0.149      0.135     0.160   0.202   0.147          
3  model1   t value      0.941       4.649      -0.769    1.560   -0.165  0.105          
4  model1 Pr(> | t| )    0.356       0.0001     0.450     0.132   0.870   0.917          
5  model2  Estimate      11.258      0.682      -0.103    0.238                          
6  model2 Std. Error     7.318       0.129      0.129     0.139                          
7  model2   t value      1.538       5.296      -0.799    1.707                          
8  model2 Pr(> | t| )    0.136      0.00002     0.432     0.100                          
9  model3  Estimate      -7.476                           0.164           -0.001  -0.062 
10 model3 Std. Error     3.570                            0.053           0.044    0.042 
11 model3   z value      -2.094                           3.079           -0.013  -1.472 
12 model3 Pr(> | z| )    0.036                            0.002           0.990    0.141 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: thanks Pkumar but this is not what I am looking for. I want just one table with three rows corresponding to the three models. Question updated.

Comment: thanks a lot PKumar, I dont see the significance stars and the standard errors are not into parenthesis but perhaps that is not possible. Let me wait a little bit to see if somebody jumps in, otherwise I will accept your answer. thanks for your time